# Can't cache google fonts

Tags: html, browser-cache, cache-manifest

I created test html page with google font

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,700italic,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And here is manifest

```
CACHE MANIFEST

NETWORK:
/api

CACHE:
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/MDadn8DQ_3oT6kvnUq_2r_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/MgNNr5y1C_tIEuLEmicLmwLUuEpTyoUstqEm5AMlJo4.woff2
```

I opened localhost (I'm using gulp serve task).
Now I can see in console (after cmd+shift which means refresh without cache):

```
GET https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/MDadn8DQ_3oT6kvnUq_2r_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2 net::ERR_FAILED
```

How can I fix this error?
Thanks.

Comment: Your first link returns a stylesheet that contains references to the fonts, and also contains references to local copies that will be used if they exist.

Comment: FWIW, I checked the HTTP headers and Google sends headers to disable caching. they have an option to download the font, but you would need to change the lined CSS file to point to the copy on your server.

If you serve the file and enable caching, it should be available locally after that.